# What timezone is Facebook Graph API using?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Cannot find this in Graph API documentation or in any FB settings, I'm in UTC+1 currently, looks like responses I get are in UTC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Made a post this morning at 11:48 am EST.  Display on FB page says 11:48 am.
Graph API says 16:48 so I'm thinking that the created_time is going to be in UTC.

I saw a post or two that said they use UTC-8 which would be pacific standard time, but according to what I'm looking at on FB and on the Graph API, I'm seeing UTC.

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Matt, it looks like UTC, just don't know why its not documented anywhere.

Comment: No worries!  Glad I could shed a little light on it.  Not a rep hound, but if you can mark that as an answer, it might save someone else the frustration by making it easier to find :)